# Accessing the mobile camera of an Android tablet using flash

Tags: android, flash

A while ago I developed a flash app that takes pictures from the users webcam, I recently bought a android tablet device (flash capable), but the flash app do not find the camera of the tablet, any way I can modify my flash app in order to "see" the tablet's camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using Flash of Flash Builder?

For Flash Builder: if you want to access a mobile camera, you need flash builder 4.5 at least. There you can call for CameraUI instead of Camera. I don't know if this is actually a feature of Flash Builder or if it is also available in Flash, since i am not using Flash Builder 4.5 just yet.

look at [this link](http://www.flex-tutorial.fr/2010/09/07/air-android-prendre-des-photos-videos-avec-cameraui/) to find a coded example of CameraUI and the implementation of it.

Comment: The API he's referencing is AIR only. Is this a browser app or a standalone air app?